# Compare the name of two images in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have this function in wordpress implemented,

```
add_action('wp_ajax_questiondatahtml', 'questiondatahtml_update');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_questiondatahtml', 'questiondatahtml_update');
function questiondatahtml_update () {
    if ($_FILES) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        $file_handler = 'updoc';
        $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file_handler, $post->ID);
    }

    echo $author_id . wp_get_attachment_image($attach_id, "large");

    wp_die();
}
```

what it does is upload images to the media library. But I need to check that the name does not exist, and I can not make it work.
Someone has an idea
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to save the image in a different and unique name (like date + random number or so).